# Move MySQL /var/lib/mysql to shared volume

Tags: mysql, docker, synology

I'm running a container with MySQL 8.0.18 in Docker on a Synology nas.  I'm just using it to support another container (Mediawiki) on that box.  MySQL has one volume mounted at path `/var/lib/mysql`.  I would like to move that to a shared volume so i can access it with File Station and also periodically back it up.  How can i move it to the `docker` share shown below without breaking MySQL?

[image]

Here are available shares on the Synology nas.

[image]

Alternatively, is there a way i can simply copy that /var/lib/mysql to the shared docker folder?  That should work as well for periodic backups.

thanks,
russ

**EDIT**: Showing result after following Zeitounator's plan.  Before running the docker command (2.) i created the `mediawiki_mysql_backups` and `12-29-2019` folders in File Station.  After running 2. and 3. all the files from mysql are here and i now have a nice backup!

[image]

Comment: Copying files is not an ideal way to backup a database. For true consistency you need to implement mirroring at the DBMS level (with MySQL that requires a cluster). Using mysqldump guarantees the physical consistency of the data but not its logical consistency, Backing up files provides neither logical nor pysical consistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Stop your current container to make sure mysql is not running.
2. Create a dummy temp container where you mount the 2 needed volumes. I tend to user busybox for this kind of tasks => `docker run -it --rm --name temp_mysql_copy -v mediaviki-mysql:/old-mysql -v /path/to/ttpe/docker:/new-mysql busybox:latest`
3. Copy all files => `cp -a /old-mysql/* /new-mysql/`
4. Exit the dummy container (which will cleanup by itself if you used my above command)
5. Create a new container with mysql:8 image mounting the new folder in `/var/lib/mysql` (you probably need to do this in your syno docker gui).
6. If everything works as expected, delete the old `mediaviki-mysql` volume

Comment: That works wonderfully.  My final version of 2. is `sudo docker run -it --rm --name temp_mysql_copy -v mediawiki-mysql:/old-mysql -v /volume1/docker/mediawiki_mysql_backups/12-29-2019:/new-mysql busybox:latest`.  The edit in my question above shows the results in the Synology File Station.